# How to start subversion server on ubuntu?

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I have a **svn** server on an ubuntu and I am connecting to it from windows client for update and commit my codes. Unfortunately my svn service goes down after few minutes. It was working great yesterday but I restarted and it's svn service goes down after a while and I need to run this code for restart svn service on server.

```
svnserve -d --foreground -r /home/svn
```

Service starts but it is not stable and goes down after a while. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. I need to run this command to force `svnserve` to stay running :

```
$ svnserve -d -r /home/svn
```